# Laravel - ERROR UPDATE and can't reset ID or AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: sql-server, laravel, single-page-application

I'm just trying to make a record that will reset the ID if reach the specified limit.

I make this migration.

```
public function up(){
        Schema::create('records', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('age');
        });
}

public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('records');
}
```

And Insert some data and the output is this.
[image]

Now, I can already insert data from my database without any problem.

I just want to have a function that can reset or alter the id on my table.

Here's the sample condition.
Example: I have a limit record of 5 then reset the id.
So if I try to insert a record then it will be greater than the limit, It will reset the id on my table to 1.

I try to make this function

```
public function insert_record(Request $request){
    $record = new Record();
    $record->name = $request->to_insert_name;
    $record->age = $request->to_insert_age;
    if($record->id == 5){
        DB::update("ALTER TABLE records AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
        Record::insert(
            [
                'name' => $request->to_insert_name;
                'age' = $request->to_insert_age;
            ]
        );
    }else{
        Record::insert(
            [
                'name' => $request->to_insert_name;
                'age' = $request->to_insert_age;
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.

I've tried another DB statement to change the sequence.

```
DB::statement("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'records'");
```

But, still got this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'SQLITE_SEQUENCE'.

How could I achieve the output like the image below?
[image]

Comment: is there id is a primary key?

Comment: Well you are trying the syntax for MySQL and SQLite but your database is SQL Server? Every database has its own SQL dialect, you need to check the documentation specific to your database. I suspect you want [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: And that said, you should never be resetting the id column, how would you then uniquely identify a record?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quiet good at sql, so i try working suggestions from site(s). The *id* is the *primary key* their *uniques* is their *code* [Sample Only](https://i.imgur.com/BEPMzsj.png). Is there any way to change/reset the id?

Answer (score 0):

The ID field is a unique value. It cannot contain duplicated values. You can do this by adding an index field of integer type to the table.

```
$table->integer('index');
```

Add this to the Record model.

```
/**
 *  Setup model event hooks
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->index = $model->index == 5 ? 1 : $model->max('index') + 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: How does actually work? how can I call it in my ```insert_record()``` function?